How to integrate the move2kube with AKS and ACR?
I am trying to use the move2kube to generate all the code, but when I run the pushImages to ACR, it leads me to an error.
Can anyone guide me on integrating the move2kube with ACR for pushing the images?
I also tried move2kube collect -a k8s, which generates the empty cluster folder. when I run kubectl to get pods, it gives me all the pods running in my AKS.
